# Using 3rd Party Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gruntjs

I am a noob at React and have gotten myself a little lost. I am creating my react in a .jsx file which I run grunt-babel on, this then gets put through grunt-uglify to concatenate it with react.js and react-dom.js (in a set order) and finally the single outputted file is then added to my html.

I am using react to build a table. I pass in an array of data for the table, but then I want to splice the array and paginate it.

I've found a 3rd party component that looks like it will do the job (https://github.com/SimonErich/react-paginatr). Now my problem is that I don't know how to actually use this with my workflow. I have tried various other 3rd party components and don't know how to get them to work either.

If I simply add the compiled PaginatrComponent.js PaginatrMixin.js in the libs folder to my uglify command after react and react-dom I get this in the console

Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at react.min.js:8320

And I doing something completely wrong? I see people making references to CommonJs and Webpack and Browserify? But am not sure what they do or how they would fit in my workflow.

My code is on codepen here http://codepen.io/rmaspero/pen/LxQNYY:

```
var INVOICES = [
  {
    state: "processing",
    number: "INV-31",
    customer: "Dael ltd",
    total: 60000,
    currency: "£",
    due: "5 Days",
    uri: "https://www.example.com/",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    state: "rejected",
    number: "INV-765",
    customer: "Dael ltd",
    total: 7430,
    currency: "€",
    due: "30 Days",
    uri: "https://www.example.com/2",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    state: "rejected",
    number: "INV-001",
    customer: "JB Towers ltd",
    total: 943,
    currency: "£",
    due: "15 Days",
    uri: "https://www.example.com/3",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    state: "draft",
    number: "INV-043",
    customer: "JB Towers ltd",
    total: 72,
    currency: "£",
    due: "10 Days",
    uri: "https://www.example.com/4",
    id: 4,
  },
  {
    state: "processing",
    number: "INV-341",
    customer: "Dael ltd",
    total: 3045,
    currency: "£",
    due: "45 Days",
    uri: "https://www.example.com/5",
    id: 5,
  },
  {
    state: "processing",
    number: "INV-501",
    customer: "JB Towers ltd",
    total: 453,
    currency: "£",
    due: "65 Days",
    uri: "https://www.example.com/6",
    id: 6,
  },
];

function Invoice(props) {
  return (
    <tr className='invoice-table--row' onClick={props.onLink}>
      <td className='invoice-table--cell invoice__state'><span className={"state__indicator indicator--" + props.state}></span><span className="state__text">{props.state}</span></td>
      <td className='invoice__number'>{props.number}</td>
      <td className='invoice__customer small-mobile-hide'>{props.customer}</td>
      <td className='invoice-table--cell'>{props.currency}{props.total}</td>
      <td className='invoice__due'>{props.due}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

Invoice.propTypes = {
  onLink: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

function TableHeadings() {
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr className='invoice-table--header'>
        <th className='invoice-table--head invoice-head__state'>State</th>
        <th className='invoice-table--head'>Inv No.</th>
        <th className='invoice-table--head small-mobile-hide'>Customer</th>
        <th className='invoice-table--head'>Total</th>
        <th className='invoice-table--head invoice-head__due'>Due</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  );
}

function TableTitle(props) {
  return (
    <div className="section-divider">
      <h3 className="section-divider__title">Processing React</h3>
      <div className="paginate">
        <a className='paginate__button' href="#"><span className="icon icon--arrow icon--large arrow--previous" data-grunticon-embed></span></a>
        <span className="paginate__text">Page 1 of 3</span>
        <a className='paginate__button' onClick={props.onPage}><span className="icon icon--arrow icon--large" data-grunticon-embed></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

TableTitle.propTypes = {
  onPage: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    rows: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    startrow: React.PropTypes.number,
    initialInvoices: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
      state: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      number: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      customer: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      total: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      currency: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      due: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    })).isRequired,
  },

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      startrow: 0,
    }
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      invoices: this.props.initialInvoices,
      rows: this.props.rows,
    };
  },

  onPageUp: function() {
    this.state.invoices.slice(this.props.startrow + this.props.row, this.props.rows);
  },

  onLinkClick: function(uri) {
     console.log(uri);
     window.location.href = (uri);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TableTitle onPage={function() {this.onPageUp()}.bind(this)}/>
        <table className='invoice-table'>
          <TableHeadings/>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.invoices.slice(this.props.startrow, this.props.rows).map(function(invoice, index) {
              return (
                <Invoice
                  state={invoice.state}
                  number={invoice.number}
                  customer={invoice.customer}
                  total={invoice.total}
                  currency={invoice.currency}
                  due={invoice.due}
                  key={invoice.id}
                  uri={invoice.uri}
                  onLink={function() {this.onLinkClick(invoice.uri)}.bind(this)}
                />
              );
            }.bind(this))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard initialInvoices={INVOICES} rows={3} totalRows={6} />, document.getElementById('dashboard-processing__table'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should definitely use a tool like Webpack or Browserfy. They allow you to pack your project making references of files way easier. [This is good explanation about Webpack](http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/). I would also add [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and use [React with ES6](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus). [The official React docs are using ES6](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and I find its syntax way better. All these tools will help you to keep each component in a separate file and they will allow you to reference and use them (or 3rd party components) straightforwardly.

You should probably check out a tutorial/boilerplate. [This one looks pretty good to me](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html) but there are plenty of resources out there.